# Update a column by each value

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

Below is my table contains duration as HH:MM:SS

[image: My Table]

i could convert it into seconds by

```
SELECT  (SUBSTRING(CAST('00:01:15' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),1,2) * 360) 
+ (SUBSTRING(CAST('00:01:15' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),4,2) * 60) 
+  SUBSTRING(CAST('00:01:15' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),7,2)
```

and now i need to update that table into seconds by reading each row of records how?

like  instead of having '00:01:15' i need each row of `@DURATIONINSECONDS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below

If your table have value like this

**Table1**

```
DurationInSeconds
00:01:15    
00:00:15    
00:01:16    
00:01:17
```

and you want to Update the field **DurationInSeconds** into Seconds...

then just try like the below query....

```
update Table1 set DurationInSeconds = (SUBSTRING(CAST(DurationInSeconds AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),1,2) * 360) + (SUBSTRING(CAST(DurationInSeconds AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),4,2) * 60) +  SUBSTRING(CAST(DurationInSeconds AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),7,2)
```

then it give the Result like below

```
SELECT * from Table1

DurationInSeconds
75
15
76
77
```

Comment: i wonder! sometimes we may have silly doubts... i think it's one of mine... gosh!!! shame....